# Setting Theme Programmactically Causes black background

Tags: android, dialog, themes

When I run my android application I am calling a method to check if the app is being run on a tablet using:

```
public boolean isTablet(Context context){
  boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
  boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)== Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK);
  return(xlarge || large);
}
```

if the method returns true(i.e. the device satisfies one of these conditions)

I set my theme to a Dialog theme via:

```
setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
```

where `MyTheme` is a theme that inherits from the parent `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog`

This logic works fine however it gives me a weird effect in the background. The Calling intent is completely blacked out, whereas if i just set the theme in the manifest the background is only slightly greyed out.

**Update - code added**

```
 private Context mClassContext = this;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     if(isTablet(mClassContext)){
       setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
     }
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
}
```

How do I replicate this?

Comment: You do the `setTheme` before `SetContentView()`?

Comment: yes, should i be moving it to after this? I am posting my `onCreate()` now

Comment: i moved code to after `setContentView()` and it doesn't set my Theme. I tried this before. If you want the theme to be set you have to do it before you call `setContentView()`. I just don't get why the background gets completely blacked out.

Comment: Yeah, the setTheme needs to be executed before the SetContentView(). I've had some real weird effects when trying to apply **Theme.Holo.Light** in an Activity with `addPreferencesFromResource()`. The background was all black, but dialogs was Light. Why you have this error I'm afraid I can't figure out. I had to put the setTheme before addPreferencesFromResource.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have seem to found the answer to my own question.

To avoid the black background:

In the android manifest set all your activities that could be dialogs(if it is a tablet) to the dialog theme:

then in `onCreate` add this else case to change it for non-tablet devices(i.e phones)

```
if(isTablet(mContext)){
setTheme(R.style.myDialogTheme);}
else{ 
  setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
}
```